# Displaying overlayed QGraphicsItems

Tags: qt5, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

I have developed an application in PyQt5 that displays an image and allows the user to pan the image using the mouse and zoom using the mouse wheel. I now need to add the functionality to show popup text associated to specific parts of the displayed image. While painting the text directly on to the QGraphicsScene is a possibility, the range of zooms that are commonly used means that the text will be much too small when zoomed out, or much too large when zoomed in.

I would like to achieve a way of placing the QGraphicsTextItem widgets at a static location that is not affected by the pan and zoom. This way, they can be statically located around the perimiter of the QGrapicsView, and I can draw a line from the text box to the position in the scene. My problem is that I cannot find a way to place the text items so they are independant of the QGraphicsScene. I am thinking that I should have the text items external to the scene, and place the QGraphicsView and any text boxes in a parent QObject. I cannot figure out if this is the best method, and have had limited success with trying to connect a line from QGraphicsElipsesItem that marks the position on the image, to a QLabel in the parent QObject.

I hope I have made this clear enough. Please comment if it needs more clarification.